# Include after select not load navigation property in Entity Framework core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I use entity framework core 1.1.

I have a query like below, and I expect to users who have UserProfile by using Include, load UserProfile.
But this query always return UserProfile null .

Query:

```
var user = dbContext.UserMappers
    .Where(e => e.OldUserId == id)
    .Select(e => e.User)
    .Include(e=>e.UserProfile)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Models:

```
public class UserMapper
{
    [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int OldUserId { get; set; }
}

public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public bool Suspended { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

From the EF Core documentation - [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) - **Ignored includes** section (highlight is mine):

> If you change the query so that it no longer returns instances of the entity type that **the query began with**, then the include operators are ignored.

This is different from EF6 where `Include` works on the final query entity type. I don't know if this is a current limitation or "by design", but for now you have to start your queries with the entity requiring includes.

In your case, it should be something like this:

```
var user = dbContext.Users
    // if you don't have inverse navigation property
    .Where(e => dbContext.UserMappers.Any(um => um.UserId == e.Id && um.OldUserId == id))
    // if you have inverse collection navigation property
    //.Where(e => e.UserMappers.Any(um.OldUserId == id))
    // if you have inverse reference navigation property
    //.Where(e => e.UserMapper.OldUserId == id)
    .Include(e => e.UserProfile)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```